# juju deploy: series does not match

Tags: juju

I ran these commands:

```
juju generate-config
juju switch manual
```

Then I edited the environment file to add the host address.

Then:

```
juju bootstrap
juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui
```

And I got the error message:

```
ERROR cannot assign unit "juju-gui/0" to machine 0: series does not match
```

I got similar errors trying to deploy mysql to another machine after add-machine
but I guess the answer to the above question can solve the other case as well.

Answer (score 3):

What is your host series? Precise? Trusty? It's likely that the default series does not match so it's trying to deploy the incorrect charm type.

Try: `juju deploy --to 0 cs:precise/juju-gui` if it's precise or "cs:trusty/juju-gui" if it's trusty.

Comment: I've received the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Three things to check:

1. Is there a `default-series` setting in your `$HOME/.juju/environments.yaml` for your environment named "manual"? If not, I think "precise" is still the default.
2. Immediately after `juju bootstrap`, run `juju status` and see what's the machine 0's "series" (e.g. "series: trusty"). The charm you're trying to deploy must match that series.
3. After running `juju deploy juju-gui --to 0`, you'll see a message like `Added charm "cs:precise/juju-gui-98" to the environment.` If the series on the machine did not match the charm series, you'll also get an error like `ERROR cannot assign unit "juju-gui/0" to machine 0: series does not match`.

So, you either deploy with explicit series, e.g. `juju deploy cs:trusty/juju-gui --to 0`, specifying a series matching machine 0's series; or alternatively, set "default-series: trusty" before bootstrap.