# Juju how to resolve this error "ERROR cannot assign unit "xxxx" to machine 1: series does not match"

Tags: juju, maas

After to make the upgrade of MaaS via ppa stable and installed Juju by ppa stable, during the deploy of the service I've received this error

```
$: juju deploy --to 1 mysql
Added charm "cs:trusty/mysql-4" to the environment.
ERROR cannot assign unit "mysql/0" to machine 1: series does not match
```

While deployed juju-gui and puppetmaster it works fine, I tried also with other service and the problem is the same.

```
juju deploy --to 1 rabbitmq-server
Added charm "cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-7" to the environment.
ERROR cannot assign unit "rabbitmq-server/0" to machine 1: series does not match
```

Some one have resolved that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [juju deploy: series does not match](http://askubuntu.com/questions/508316/juju-deploy-series-does-not-match)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that it was finding the precise versions of juju-gui and puppermaster.

You could try the following commands to force getting the precise charms:

```
juju deploy cs:precise/mysql
juju deploy cs:precise/rabbitmq-server
```

Comment: Alternatively, specify "default-series: trusty" in your environments.yaml before bootstrap.